# What would "kiwi" be in Latin?

Tags: word-request

What would kiwi be in Latin? Both the bird and the fruit. I guess there's no actual word because I don't think they had kiwis, but what would you guess it to be if you had to use it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you wondering what an ancient Roman might have called kiwis if they'd been introduced by an exotic foreign merchant, or what a mediaeval philosopher might have called them, or what a modern-day author might call them?

Comment: Hi Kiwi! I have closed this question because you have not edited your question in response to comments requesting clarification. Please edit the question to answer the question @Draconis asks and explain what you are looking for. The question can be reopened if you edit to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

For the fruit, before the kiwifruit was rebranded as the kiwifruit by New Zealand growers in the '60s and '70s it was called the Chinese gooseberry, because it's from China and tastes like gooseberries.

I'm not aware of a classical term for gooseberry (there surely must have been one, but I can't find it), but in New Latin there's *grossullus* < French *groseille* < MDutch *kroesel* = *kruisbes* (the double *s* is a result of confusion with the diminutive of *grossus* 'unripe fig'). Alternatively, you could just use *bāca* 'berry'.

The Romans had two terms for the Chinese: *Sīnae* and *Seres*. The latter effectively referred to the Chinese reachable by the overland Silk Route, the former to those reachable by sea. If the Romans had known the kiwifruit it probably would have come to them by sea, so we need the former. The adjective is *sinica* or *Sinēnsis*.

I would go with either **grossullus Sinēnsis** (which feels more New Latin to me) or **bāca sinica** (if you want to be more classical).

Answer (score 0):

Apteryx is the scientific name for a kiwi

Comment: But what would the Romans say?

Comment: @Kiwi Can you please edit your question to make your goal more specific? See the comment under your question. Are you only looking for a word that a Roman might use, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "Pomus Aliena." "Foreign Fruit." And "Avis Alienus/Aliena." "Foreign Bird." If one had no one to explain it to them, this would likely be their first instinct.

If a foreign merchant were to display one of these things, he might tell you that it is a "Kivi" or "Civi" from Nova Zeelandia. They weren't averse to just Romanizing foreign words.

The other possibility, that they would come up with an entirely Roman moniker, is unlikely but possible. If this is the sort of question you're asking, you might get better results appealing to the chat for this stack exchange: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=latin.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think your answer provides a way of *referring* to a kiwi bird/fruit, but not a name. In this case, "pomum alienum" would be quite ambiguous without context.

Comment: I favor the borrowing and latinization the best; it feels to me the most like what might actually happen if a trader or merchant brought kiwi fruit or birds to Rome and verbally told people, "this is kiwi". Using the  _K_  has the benefit of preserving more of the original spelling but reducing the chances of mistaking it for declensions of other words.